# Bios: Hard drive not detected, is there something wrong with my SSD or RAM?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, sony-vaio, memory-leaks

I've had a Sony Vaio SVP13218PGB for 7~8 years now. My laptop kept on shutting down and the BIOS showed 'hard disk not detected'. Usually what I did to recover it was to let it rest for a while after trying turning it off and on until I can boot it normally again. It always crashed whenever my local C: storage took up more than half of its disk space (usually 80GB/140GB when it crashed).

I've tried to clean my storage diligently every now and then, but a few weeks ago it happened again and I've had enough of it. After some research, (the first thing that came up to my mind was I need more storage) I found that this laptop's RAM cannot be upgraded because it's been soldered in and I could only upgrade the SSD.

I'm contemplating on fixing what I can first (upgrading the SSD?) rather on buying a new laptop cause I have a limited budget. The more I read about this computer the more I think my RAM could've been the cause of this problem too (?).

When I open the task manager it shows this:

[image: My Task Manager]
[image: The Performance]
[image: Resource Monitor]

Do I have memory leak that could lead to all the problems I've had so far? I've noticed my laptop's fan sounds louder than usual. Are all of these related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RAM is defective, the machine probably will not start. The message you get says the System Drive is defective and getting more defective as you keep using it.

You need to replace the drive in this case.

Comment: So the solution is to replace the SSD?

Comment: Yes that is what you need to do

Comment: based on the picture I linked in, is it okay to have my memory took up to 80% when I only open this site and task manager?

Comment: Probably.  I think your memory is working

Comment: Okay, thank you!!